# Angular CLI - unable to create new project - error: 401 Unauthorized: core-js

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am having a problem after `brew upgrade; brew update`.
Used to be able to create Angular project with CLI with: `ng new my-app` but today it is showing error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: core-js@^2.5.4
```

I am trying this in a brand new folder (or any folder). For test - used: `/tmp/test/` folder.

My current installation for software/tools:

```
npm -v
6.1.0

node -v
v10.6.0

ng -v
Angular CLI: 6.1.3
```

Comment: Please try uninstalling, clearing cache and reinstalling npm and angular-cli! It may solve your problem.

Comment: what @alokstar said - I've never installed `ng` until literally just now so i was on fresh copy of ng@7.0.6, npm@6.4.x, node@11.2.0. so uninstall `ng` and reinstall it via npm. It seems weird that it's giving you a 401 error b/c it seems to be trying to download the `core-js` package that is behind some sort of authentication.

Comment: @hellatan: yes, that was just to make sure everything is clean. unauthorized means you also might want to check the registry point for npm.

Comment: Can someone please post the sequence of proper way to uninstall/clear cache of several tools mentioned? I tried few uninstall that found on goolge search but still no luck..